# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Blender has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: quellenform]

[image: Robin Betts]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6025697091911680).

Comment: Congratulations! Looking forward to see both of you join our moderation team.

Comment: Congrats to the winners and welcome to the team. And thanks to Allen Simpson for participating as well.

Comment: Duarte: agreed: a special shout-out and thanks to @Allen Simpson for volunteering.

Comment: Congratulations @quellenform and Robin! I apologize for not [running](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2987/65455) in the end, but figured there were enough candidates who also seemed to be a lot more in their element.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. Counting on you for the next election ;)